# How a non normal distribution indicate that a sample differs from the population?

Tags: statistics

I'm using an introductory to statistics book and it mentioned this:

"What is perhaps most important to keep in mind is that a non-normal distribution of scores may be an indication that a sample differs in important and systematic ways from the population that it is supposed to represent."

Can someone give me examples/situation where this applies?

Comment: Is the assumption that the population has a normal distribution and so a non-normal distribution of the samples suggests a difference?  How does this deal with the situation where the population does not have a normal distribution? How would you know?

Comment: I thought that it was convention to assume the population is normally distributed?

Comment: @Henry, your comment should be an answer, it is good.

Comment: @user65141 it is convention in books...real life is not always so. If you take a bunch if clever mathematicians, their score in GMAT will show full marks...Not Normal indeed.

Comment: @NoChance - my comment is three questions rather than an answer.  Feel free to answer yourself

Comment: @Henry, I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under certain conditions, the population's scores will have a Normal distribution, or an approximate Normal distribution. (For example, if the score is a sum of many finite-variance variables, this can be argued from a suitable version of the central limit theorem, although the version used can impose specific additional requirements to verify, such as sufficiently rapid tail decay in the variables' distributions.) If this is the case, genuinely representative samples ought to seem Normal. Normality tests of samples can show this null hypothesis has a low $p$-value. In principle this could mean the sample is non-representative or a Normal approximation fails for the full population, but if the latter is implausible we'd entertain the former explanation.